# QueryDsl Set Schema

Tags: java, spring, db2, h2, querydsl

Using a Spring `DataSource` and a QueryDsl `SQLQueryImpl`, how do you specify the schema or set the schema?

Test case is:

1. Use querydsl-maven-plugin (2.9.0) to connect to DB2 database to generate Q-Classes specifying `<schemaPattern>`
2. Spring creates a `DataSource` bean
3. `DataSource` bean is populated by scripts (`CREATE SCHEMA FOO`, `CREATE TABLE FOO.BAR` etc)
4. JUnit test imports `DataSource`
5. Query using `new SQLQueryImpl(dataSource.getConnection(), Configuration.DEFAULT)`

Error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "BAR" not found; SQL Statement: ...
```

Note that this test implementation is an H2 database, but the production database is DB2.  So far I've tried specifying the schema in the JDBC connection strings to no avail.

Comment: What is your database URL for the H2 database?

Comment: Database url is `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`.  I cannot specify the schema in the connection URL because the schema does not exist yet.  The `ResourceDatabasePopular` is invoked after the database is created, and the `CREATE SCHEMA` statement(s) are executed after that.

Comment: You could use the `INIT` feature to create the schema when opening the database URL (`jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to extend `SQLTemplates` with my own implementation that called the protected method `setPrintSchema(true);`.

Answer (score 4):

`com.mysema.query.sql.SQLTemplates` has a builder method called `printSchema()`. Initialise `SQLTemplates` using the `builder()` method and call `printSchema()` before `build()`. Example to follow:

```
SQLTemplates templates = OracleTemplates.builder().printSchema().build();
```

Answer (score 2):

The Schema is encoded in the Q-types. It is accessed in the SQL serialization via the RelationalPath interface http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.9.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/sql/RelationalPath.html

Comment: Yes, the schema name (`FOO`) is accessible via the `getSchemaName()` , but the generated SQL is not fully qualified. 
Expected: `SELECT COL1 FROM FOO.BAR`.  Actual: `SELECT COL1 FROM BAR`.